# How to convert hibernate join query to ormlite query

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I have a hibernate query which selects particular data from two tables using its model class based on certain conditions.  Now i want to convert that query to ORMLite query to use in my android application, but I didn't know how to do it using queryBuilder() in ORMLite because I am a beginner in ORMLite.

```
Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(
    "SELECT A.accountID,A.name,B.allowTransactions from Payments A,Accounts B "
    + "WHERE A.accountID=B.id AND B.id NOT IN (5,55,602) AND A.active=1 AND "
    + "B.parentID=:pID AND B.date BETWEEN :sDate AND :eDate GROUP BY A.id "
    + "ORDER BY CASE WHEN A.name=:name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,A.name");
query.setParameter("pID",4);
query.setParameter("name", "Others");
query.setParameter("sDate",startDate);
query.setParameter("eDate", endDate);
```

Below are the getter method for Payments and Accounts classes.

```
dbHelper.getPaymentDao() and dbHelper.getAccountDao()
```

Comment: looks like no one is familiar with ORMLite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a hibernate query which selects particular data from two tables using its model class based on certain conditions. Now i want to convert that query to ORMLite query...

This query is not supported by ORMLite's `QueryBuilder` given its complexity.  You can certainly use the [`dao.queryRaw(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)) and then process the results yourself by hand.

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> results = paymentDao.queryRaw(
    "SELECT A.accountID,A.name,B.allowTransactions from Payments A,Accounts B "
    + "WHERE A.accountID=B.id AND B.id NOT IN (5,55,602) AND A.active=1 AND "
    + "B.parentID=? AND B.date BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY A.id "
    + "ORDER BY CASE WHEN A.name = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,A.name",
    parentId, fromDate, toDate, name);
```

Notice that I've converted the : args into `?` arguments.

That returns `String` results but you can also use the other `Dao.queryRaw(...)` methods to properly convert the results into Java entities.

See: http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries

Comment: Is there any library needed for queryRaw() function?

Comment: I'm not understanding that question @KJEjava48.  `queryRaw(...)` is a method on the DAO.

Comment: here both Accounts and Payments table are used,so which dao class i need to use?How would i get the selected field only by using paymentDao?

Comment: Once you use the `queryRaw(...)`, you can access any fields/entities so you could use either one @KJEjava48.